# how to write either this variable or that variable in php after foreach loop

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to fetch values from two tables using join queries that has distinct values. I.e. table one's id is update_id and table two's id is g_id.

My question is how to write it in such a way that the for each loop prints the exact variables without failing to print the table 1 variables and table 2 variables when table 2 or table 1 variable is fetched. So far I've written like this

```
($update_id || $g_id)
```

to print either $update_id or $g_id in html tags, i.e.

```
$more="<button class='btn btn-link more' data-id='".($updateid||$postid)."'>...More</button>";
```

but it isn't working.

Can you suggest any better methods. I'll provide the full code if you want to but got to warn its lengthy.

Comment: Can you clarify what you want printed exactly and in what cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use ternary operator. that might help

```
$more="<button class='btn btn-link more' data-id='".($updateid?$updateid:$postid)."'>...More</button>";
```

so that if there is $updateid it will echo out $updateid else it will echo $postid

Comment: Event shorter $updateid ?? $postid. For PHP7 or above